# C++ Conditional For Loop, independent counter

Tags: c++, for-loop, counter

I am writing some code for counting the number of vowels within a given word, I have already completed some run of mill code, however I was wondering if it was possible to do something along these lines

```
bool isVowel(char inputcharacter)  //Bool function to check the validity of a character as being a bool
{
    set<char> Vowels{'a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U'};  //Pre-Makes a set of characters (Specifically Vowels) Used to check characters
    
    if (Vowels.find(inputcharacter) != Vowels.end())  //if the character is found within the list, before the list's end, the return will be true (Theoreticle indexing element that extends beyond the "physical" list)
    {
        return true;  //Returns a true value
    }
    return false;  //Returns a false value else
}
int numVowels(string inputstring)  //Vowelcounter function
{
    int Contained_Vowels = 0;  //Intializes the counter to be 0
    for (char c : inputstring; (isVowel(c) == true); Contained_Vowels++);
    return Contained_Vowels;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Also your numVowels function does not return vowel numbers of inputstring, but return numbers of continuous vowels in inputstring.

Comment: no, just use an if statement in the body of the for loop or get rid of the for loop all together by using `std::count_if`

Comment: my question is, is it possible to make some code that is similar to the for loop in numVowels, numVowels doesn't return anything at the moment, because the for loop has an error. So is there any way of creating a logic type circuit in the for loop

Comment: Something similar to List comprehension, but for loop comprehension
Python List Comprehension
tempList = [(i[0], i[2]) for i in data if i[1] == 'fruit']

Comment: Something along those lines is `for (char c: inputstring) Contained_Vowels += isVowel(c);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your specific question is already given in comments.

I would like to add an alternative, a maybe more sophisticated function, implemented as Lambda. So, the whole stuff can be done in one statement.

Please first look at the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string test{"Hello World"};
    
    auto numberOfVowels = [](const std::string&s) -> size_t 
        {return std::count_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](const char c) { return (0x208222 >> (c & 0x1f)) & 1; });};

    std::cout << numberOfVowels(test) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I know that the following will be hard to digest. I want to show it anyway, because it is the "more-modern C++"-solution.

So, I will first think and develop an algorithm, and then use moderen C++ elements to implement it.

First to the algorithm. If we use the ASCII code to encode letters, then we will see the following:

[image: Ascci Code for Letters]

We see that the ASCII code for uppercase and lowercase letters just differ in the lower 5 bits. So, if we mask the ASCII code with 0x1F, so `char c{'a'}; unsigned int x{c & 0x1F}`, we will get values between 1 and 26. So, we can calculte a 5 bit value for each letter. If we now mark all vowels with a 1, we can build a binary number, consisting of 32bits (an unsigned int) and set a bit at each position, where the vowel is true. We then get something like

```
Bit position
3322 2222 2222 1111 1111 1100 0000 0000  
1098 7654 3210 9876 5432 1098 7654 3210  
Position with vowels:
0000 0000 0010 0000 1000 0010 0010 0010
```

This numer can be converted to 0x208222. And if we now want to find out, if a letter (regardless whether upper- or lowercase) is a vowel, then we mask out the not necessary bits from the chararcter ( C & 1F ) and shift the binary number to the right as much position, as the resulting letter code has. If then the bit is set at the LSB position, then we have a vowel. This know how is decades old.

Aha. Not so easy, but will work for ASCII coded letters.

Next, we create a Lambda, that will take a string that purely consists of alpha letters and counts the vowels.

Then we use modern C++ elements to calculate the requested values:

Please note:

There are one million possible solutions. Everbody can do, what he wants.

Some people are still more in a C-Style mode and others do like more to program in C++

Comment: I cannot follow very well, however thank you very much.